# Add bottom border to columns by row, but not the last + responsive

Tags: javascript, php, css

Basically I'm displaying an varying amount of columns (cells, it's based on Foundation) in a grid. 3 column span on desktop, 2 on tablet and 1 on mobile.
I need to add a border bottom to each column but NOT on below columns of the bottom row. Please see image as an example.

[image: layout having 1, 2 or 3 columns based on screen size]

I have tried css nth child but can't count the columns with that (at least I think). So looking to achieve this programatically with php or js. But... I've to no clue where or how to tackle this issue!!! Any help is much appreciated!

This is the code I've got so far:

```
<section class="inbegrepen">
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-1 medium-up-2 large-up-3">

        <?php

        if( have_rows('inbegrepen') ):

            $i = 1;

            while( have_rows('inbegrepen') ): the_row();

                $title = get_sub_field('inbegrepen_titel');
                $content = get_sub_field('inbegrepen_tekst');

                ?>

                <div class="cell">
                    <h6><span><?php echo $i; ?></span> <?php echo $title; ?></h6>
                    <?php echo $content; ?>
                </div>

                <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using a repeating gradient over the container.

Here is a simplified example

```css
.container {
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom, 
        transparent 0, transparent calc(110px - 2px),
        red calc(110px - 2px),red calc(110px + 1px)) 
        top/100% calc(100% - 5px);
        
  /*to illustrate*/
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fill,minmax(100px,1fr));
  grid-column-gap:5px;
  animation:change 5s linear infinite alternate;
}
.container > div {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:100px;
  margin:5px 0;
  background:grey;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {width:600px}
  to {width:200px}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! This would work very nicely if the columns were same height. The content will be text based so could be varying heights.

Comment: @BramRoos your screenshot is showng equal height :)

Comment: Realise I should've mentioned. Sorry!